# Which books do I need to play TORG?

Tags: torg

I've done some research and it looks like there are tens of books for TORG (the other roleplaying game). One of them is the core book but I can't pin it down on any shopping site.

When I do, is this the only book needed to play? *I get the feeling there is more to this game than one core book.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Torg originally came out in bits; the core box had the basic system rules, drama cards, and the 'world book' that described enough of each of Torg's realms to get the GM started until the realm sourcebooks came out. (Also an adventure book with a starting adventure.)

Realm sourcebooks provided details on the different realms and also completed the rules, one topic at a time.  (For example, the magic rules were in the sourcebook for Aysle, the fantasy realm, and the weird science and pulp fiction superpowers were in the Nile Empire sourcebook.)

The book I think you're referring to is the Torg Revised and Expanded rulebook. This rulebook was assembled by Torg's most dedicated fan-writer, Jim Ogle - basically it's all the core rules assembled in one place, with some editing and tidy up, and is effectively "Torg 1.5".  However, this rulebook is a core rule book; it doesn't contain the world source material, or the drama deck - it was intended as an update rulebook for existing GMs, not a replacement for the core box set.  To go with it there was an 'Accessory pack' which included everything from the original core box set except the rulebook.

The game uses a 'drama deck' of cards, originally available only in the core box set.  The rules *can* be made to work fine without it, but a big part of Torg's strength is the way that the deck encouraged unconventional combat actions and created player control of the plot.

The deck was later sold separately so you may have luck finding it independently.  For a while it was available on RPGNow in PDF, but that seems no longer to be the case.  You can however still get [the drama deck from the successor game system](http://www.rpgnow.com/product_info.php?products_id=87230), MasterBook; this is similar enough that it can be made to work OK.  (For people who use FileMaker, there's an old [Filemaker drama card database](http://www.db.erau.edu/~taylorg/torg/cards/dramadeckdownload.html) that will print the cards.)

So, short form:

You *could* run Torg from just the core box set, or the Revised and Expanded rulebook.  But you probably shouldn't, because you'll be missing most of the strengths of the drama deck and the cross-genre realms, and without those there's no reason to play Torg at all.  (At that point, Feng Shui would be a better choice.)

To run Torg *well*, I'd recommend a minimum of:

- **Either** the original core box set **or** the revised and expanded rulebook with a separately bought or home-printed drama deck.

Plus at least any two of:

- The Aysle sourcebook (The fantasy realm and magic rules.)
- The Nile Empire sourcebook (The pulp hero realm with weird science and pulp power rules.)
- The Cyberpapacy sourcebook (A fun cyberpunk medieval-church realm, with the cybertech rules. Detailed netrunning rules were in the GodNet sourcebook, which is optional unless your group has a decker character and will spend a lot of time in the cyberpapacy.)
- The Orrorsh sourcebook (The Victorian horror realm and monsters.)
- The Kanawa sourcebook (Modern-day cyberpunk corporate espionage, with extra ninja and the martial arts rules.)

Rules-wise the Aysle sourcebook was originally the most critical, as several realms have *some* form of magic, but there's a bare-minimum spell list and magic rules in the Torg R&E book.

Good luck.  Torg is hard to find now but well worth the effort; I'd argue it was the most creatively forward-looking RPG of the early 90s, implementing very early many of the great ideas that RPG design now takes for granted.

(In particular: Torg did cinematic combat before Feng Shui, multiple game character styles on an integrated system before World of Darkness, player control of plot before just about *anybody*, and a global integrated metaplot affected by local groups' results before... well, actually, nobody's managed it since.  LFR is fun but doesn't come close.)

Comment: Sorry -- what is LFR?

Comment: @JimKiley: Living Forgotten Realms; the official D&D ongoing global campaign.  I probably shouldn't have abbreviated that on a non-D&D question.

Comment: A PDF of the Torg drama deck is now available [on DriveThru](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/19637/Torg-Drama-Deck?manufacturers_id=3444&it=1).

Comment: The question is about playing the original edition of TORG, which is not a question that can become obsolete. (For technical reasons I've removed the part of the question asking about the future — that's not something we can have questions about, because it causes problems as the future becomes the past.) If you want to mention TORG Eternity that's cool, but please not in a way that says “everything else is obsolete now” or that otherwise makes the answer less useful to players of the original game.

Comment: I see your point, @SevenSidedDie, but I would argue that this question is about playing _any_ edition of Torg, since it's a new-player-where-do-I-start request, just from a time when there was only one edition.  If anyone is so new to Torg that this question is useful to them in the first place, it's doing them a large disservice not to mention that there's a newer version AND that it's a better place to start.  The advice I gave six years ago is now horribly bad advice to a new player looking to grasp Torg.

Comment: @Tynam A rewrite to include both is reasonable, so long as it doesn’t start from the idea that wanting more information about starting with classic TORG (how the Q is approaching the “how to start” problem) is unreasonable or obsolete. The usual way to do this is to still answer the question, but offer more: “Well you can find these books, etc, etc, … And hey, there’s a new edition. If you want an easy way to play TORG and don’t care about edition, consider…” Do the rewrite with the idea that this Q’s audience will be *both* people wanting any TORG, and people wanting a guide to classic TORG.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You're correct, as usual.  I'll try for a comprehensive-overview edit when I get a minute.